# C++ Proper way of deleting a new struct array that contains new struct array?

Tags: c++

What is the proper way of deleting a new struct array that contains new struct array?

```
typedef struct CALF_STRUCTURE
{
    char* Name;
    bool IsBullCalf;
} CALF;

typedef struct COW_STRUCTURE
{
    CALF* Calves;
} COW;

int main( void )
{
    COW* Cows;
    Cows = new COW[ 3 ];                // There are 3 cows.

    Cows[ 0 ].Calves = new CALF[ 2 ];   // The 1st cow has 2 calves.
    Cows[ 1 ].Calves = new CALF[ 1 ];   // The 2nd cow has only 1 calf.
    Cows[ 2 ].Calves = new CALF[ 25 ];  // The 3rd cow has 25 calves. Holy cow!

    Cows[ 2 ].Calves[ 0 ].Name = "Bob"; // The 3rd cow's 1st calf name is Bob.

    // Do more stuff...
```

Now, its time do clean-up! But...what is the proper way of deleting the cows and calves array or any type of struct array?

Should I delete all of the cows's calves array in a for-loop first? Like this:

```
// First, delete all calf struct array (cows[x].calves)
for( ::UINT CowIndex = 0; CowIndex != 3; CowIndex ++ )
    delete [ ] Cows[ CowIndex ].Calves;

// Lastly, delete the cow struct array (cows)
delete [ ] Cows;

return 0;
};
```

Or should I just simply delete the cows array and hope that it will also delete all calves array? Like this:

```
// Done, lets clean-up
delete [ ] Cows;

return 0;
};
```

Or?

Comment: In C++, you shouldn't use `new`, and you absolutely never should use `new[]`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Really? Can you please explain why?

Comment: See @Luchian's answer. In almost every situation, something like that will be *far* preferable to any kind of manual management of dynamic allocations. (A raw `new` *might* be appropriate inside some low-level library code (even your own), but array-`new` is basically never suitable and array-like collections should be constructed with allocators.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. To do this in C++:

```
struct CALF
{
    std::string Name;
    bool IsBullCalf;
};
```

and

```
struct COW
{
    std::vector<CALF> Calves;
};
```

and, in `main`:

```
std::vector<COW> Cows(3);
```

By magic, you no longer need to delete anything.

Comment: Wow, that is perfect! Thank you. I am going to learn more about the standard vector.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to manually delete nested arrays.

But since you are using C++ forget about arrays and just use `std::vector`:

```
typedef struct COW_STRUCTURE
{
    std::vector<CALF> calves;
} COW;

int main( void ) {
  std::vector<COW> cows;
```

Why don't you want to use something that will manage everything for you in an efficient and moreover safe way?

Just as a side info:

- type names usually are not all capitalized (eg. `Cow` or `cow` but rarely `COW`), capitalization is for constants
- variables are usually camel case or lowercase with underscore (so `calves` not `Calves`)

Comment: Thanks for answering and giving me some other tips about declaring variables.